# Is there a word that means "what a shame"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word that means "what a shame!"?

Here's the context: there's a women, Cher Lair, being interviewed on The Ellen DeGeneres Show. She's a mother of 6 sons and has finally found out she is pregnant with a daughter - her dream come true. Her husband tells Ellen that, having given up hope of ever having a girl, they gave away the box of baby girl's clothes Cher had been collecting over the years. Here is what I'm trying to say:

> "When Steven explains they are going to have to start over with shopping for the girl, Cher interrupts with the minor verb phrase “I did”, emphasising the irony and *[what a shame!]* of giving away the box."

The only word I can think of is *misfortune*. Does anyone know a word meaning "what a shame!" that fits into the sentence?

Comment: I wonder if you didn't misunderstand the meaning of "I did" in the above-described exchange.

Comment: Maybe [*pity*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pity) (noun definition 2).

Comment: What’s wrong with ***shame*** itself?

Comment: Your sentence asks for the nature of the feeling while the title asks for how one would express the situation.  "**Frustration**" might be the result of an "unfortunate" "mishap" ... situations that (as other answers suggest) might make you want to say "shit" or "alas" or "heck" as an  outward expression of "frustration" .  Are you looking for the name of the emotion or ways of expressing that emotion ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess **unfortunately** would work well here.
Or if you want to be less formal then sustaining the word **shit** would also work.

Answer (score 1):

**blow**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blew+it)

> To ruin, mishandle, or fail to capitalize on an opportunity

As in:

"Cher interrupts with:  "I blew it”.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Alas](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alas)** can be used to express sadness or feeling sorry about something.

Or

> **[Heck](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heck?a=british)** (exclamation or noun): an expression of usually slight anger or surprise, or a way of adding force to a statement, question,
>   etc.:
>
> *Oh heck! It's later than I thought*.

Or

> **[aw shucks](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aw-shucks)** (exclamation):used to show that you feel embarrassed or shy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not one hundred percent sure if this is going to work, but I think you should give some thought to the noun **regret**:

> a feeling of sadness, repentance, or disappointment over an occurrence or something that one has done or failed to do. ([source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/regret))

I guess, this is what the sentence would look like now (maybe you should rewrite it slightly, changing *regret* to *her regret* or something like that):

> When Steven explains they are going to have to start over with shopping for the girl, Cher interrupts with the minor verb phrase "I did", emphasizing the irony and **regret** of giving away the box.

Answer (score 0):

waste

> "“I did”, emphasising the irony and waste of giving away the box."

waste
3. To fail to take advantage of or use for profit; lose: waste an opportunity.
[Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/waste)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking "ruefulness," "regretfulness," or "remorsefulness" might fit here.  Or maybe "with an air of self-reproach."